# Cracked Ceiling Joist

Tags: structural, remodeling

I am installing new cabinets, and when I removed the kitchen soffit, I saw one joist with a horizontal crack that goes all the way through the joist and travels about 8 inches down the length from the hanger. Can this be repaired with steel plates? Any help is appreciated.

[image: crack at joist hanger]

Comment: Given that it's supported by the hanger (and being nailed into the hanger while damp is likely what cracked it when it dried out, by the way) I don't think you need to repair it at all - but sandwiching it with plywood and glue and screws, or metal plates should be fine if it makes you more comfortable.

Comment: That looks like the joist is heart wood, notice the pattern almost a long v. This is one reason today’s lumber is lower quality, they took the ring count out so heart wood of younger trees could be used. As long as the split is running straight as it looks to be I would not worry about it.